# Product To Manage Regression Test Suite

Tags: test-management, manual-testing, test-design, regression-testing

I am looking to manage my manual regression test suite in a more professional manner and in a way that helps my QA personnel do their jobs easier. As such I was looking for a product that can help out with this but so far the only ones I've seen are Microsoft's Test Manager (MTM) and zest-testing.com both of which are far from optimal.

Are there any good pieces of software out there that can help with managing test cases and test runs as well as optimizations?

Answer (score 2):

There are many such tools. Basically if you do a search with term "test management tool" you will find a lot of alternatives. There are also many sites listing the tools, but they seem to be biased towards some commercial alternatives. One site with a quite exhaustive listing for Test tools is https://www.testtoolreview.de/en/

The company I'm working in ended up in [Meliora Testlab](https://www.melioratestlab.com/why-test-management/) as SaaS. I especially like the responsive interface that shows the right things and I don't need to do so much extra clicks like on some tools.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion can be Test Link, its freeware. You can easily install and configure at your end. This tool will help you to maintain a regression repository consisting of Test Case, Test Scripts, Test Run, Bugs etc..

Answer (score 0):

[Checkpanel](https://checkpanel.com/regression-testing) is a free online tool for managing recurring checks like regression tests.

It is extremely easy to use, not overloaded and logs all test results for future reference. It has multi user support. You can define how often you want to test each item and be reminded of overdue tests.

Disclosure: I am the founder of Checkpanel.